# why do i have to use mb_convert_encoding($name,'ISO-8859-15','utf-8') to get accented chars to display?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding

the data im working with here is off of a page that uses utf8 encoding

i've set my database and fields to use utf8_general_ci

now for whatever reason, i have to use the following code on the variable in order to have it display accented characters correctly in the database:

```
mb_convert_encoding($name,'ISO-8859-15','utf-8');
```

this makes no sense to me. why do i have to convert it to ISO-8859-15 when phpmyadmin is in utf8, the data is in utf8, and the database and table fields are in utf8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have not set your database *connection* to UTF-8, so your database expects you to send ISO-8859 encoded data. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: character set client utf8
(Global value) latin1
character set connection utf8
(Global value) latin1
character set database latin1
character set filesystem binary
character set results utf8
(Global value) latin1
character set server latin1
character set system utf8

Comment: looks like some of the variables are set to latin1, im assuming this is what you mean? i cant find in the INI where to change it though...

Comment: For each new connection, after connecting, issue the query `SET NAMES utf8` or use [`mysql_set_charset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php). Since it's not uncommon that you can't change the ini settings on production, this is the most portable method.

Comment: mysql_query("set names utf8"); worked perfectly. i figured doing this once would take, didn't realize you had to do it upon each new connection. thank you.