# Why does a string with the same encoding renders differently on MySQL and HTML?

Tags: php, mysql, html, encoding

This is the **input** string that I entered in my HTML form:

> 람다 대수(λ -, lambda -)는 함수 정의, 함수 적용, 귀납적 함수를 수식으로 표현하기 위한 형식 체계이다.
>   1930년대 알론조 처치가 수학기초론을 연구하는 과정에서 람다 대수의 형식을 제안하

This is the string that appears in MySQL **database** field of `TINYTEXT` type:

> ëžŒë‹¤ ëŒ€ìˆ˜(Î» -, lambda -)ëŠ” í•¨ìˆ˜ ì •ì˜, í•¨ìˆ˜ ì ìš©,
>   ê·€ë‚©ì  í•¨ìˆ˜ë¥¼ ìˆ˜ì‹ìœ¼ë¡œ í‘œí˜„í•˜ê¸° ìœ„í•œ í˜•ì‹ ì²´ê³„ì´

This is the **output** on the HTML page upon querying:

> 람다 대수(λ -, lambda -)는 함수 정의, 함수 적용, 귀납적 함수를 수식으로 표현하기 위한 형식 체계이

Both the HTML and the database are encoded in `UTF-8`. There are two things which I would like to ask:

1. Why does the field in MySQL database render differently from the ones in HTML?
2. What can I do to catch the length in bytes of the above string to
   ensure it is within the 255 limit of `TINYTEXT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the most common pitfall: You're not setting your database ***connection*** to the right encoding. See [why do i have to use mb_convert_encoding($name,'ISO-8859-15','utf-8') to get accented chars to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045118/why-do-i-have-to-use-mb-convert-encodingname-iso-8859-15-utf-8-to-get-acc/8045143#8045143).

Comment: How about my second question?

Comment: Because Unicode characters store 2-3 times more bytes than ASCII, You can probably only store up to 85 **characters**, because they can be up to 255 **bytes**. Use an INT.

Comment: @Ben Since UTF-8 storage in MySQL in VARCHAR/TEXT columns is rather complex, I don't have an answer for that. I'd suggest you don't limit yourself to TINYTEXT if you plan on storing anything more than a handful of characters.

Comment: @Gustav Bertram, are you answering for deceze? INT does not store text.

Comment: Use INT to store the **length** of the text. 255 is too small, because with unicode 1 character = 1-3 bytes. Also, not answering **for** deceze, just helping out.

Comment: @deceze, thanks for your honest answer. Do you think I should use VARCHAR(255) instead of TINYTEXT for storing 255 characters?

Comment: @Gustav Bertram, thanks for helping out :) I think you have misunderstood my 2nd question. I want to validate that the storage capacity for `TINYTEXT` is not exceeded. Not to store the length of text.

Comment: @Ben I'd just use a TEXT field for starters. You can run diagnostics on your database once it's populated with data to get the actual usage and a recommendation on the best size of the field, but I see no advantage of specifically limiting yourself from the beginning when it's not clear how limiting it will be. Especially if it means introducing additional complexity on the app side.

Comment: @deceze, I have converted all instances of `latin1` in character set and collation related system variables to `UTF8` and realise that it still produces the same string in my database field as described above after restarting my server and re-entering the same input.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I saw `TINYINT` not `TINYTEXT`. I agree, use TEXT, make it smaller later.

Comment: @Ben Are you setting the database ***connection*** to UTF-8 as well by issuing `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting to the database?!

Comment: @deceze, `SET NAMES 'utf8'` is equivalent to `SET character_set_client = utf8; SET character_set_results = utf8; SET character_set_connection = utf8;`. I did a `SET CHARACTER SET utf8` followed by updating my.cnf file with `character-set-server=utf8
`. All the system variables that `SET NAMES` changes are in utf8 now.

Comment: @deceze, you are right. Seems like `SET NAMES` is required before each query. How do I make it a permanent thing?